# Subscribe to a Redis Server through VueJS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, redis, graphql, apollo

I am currently working on an application with the current tech stack:

Backend:

- Mongoose
- Express
- Apollo
- GraphQL

Frontend:

- Vuejs
- Apollo
- GraphQL

So since I am a beginner with GraphQL I had no idea that apollo's inbuilt subscribe **PubSub** cannot be used in production and has no method of scaling without using services like **Redis**.

That being said, I have started a local Redis server for testing it, I managed to start a Redis Client in the backend using [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) and it connects fine to the Redis server. I have now a problem that I can't start this up on my Vue frontend in order to receive messages being published by my backend. The creator of [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) suggested that it is only for backends and I should use something else for the frontend.

I am currently confused as to how should I go about listening or subscribing to the redis server from my Vue frontend so I can receive published messages? Maybe I am looking at this in the wrong way? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I have already done this with apollo/graphql's inbuilt subscribe but like mentioned, it can't be scaled.